# Capture Linux Process ID in a Variable For A Process That is Running

Tags: linux, bash

When I run a command in a Linux script that starts a process, I'd like to capture the process number for that command in a variable for later use (i.e. to kill it later on).

Here's the command that starts the process

```
./run external
```

Would it be something like:

```
./run external/ pid=$!?
```

Manually I do: `ps -ef|grep run`, which gives me a process ID and then I can kill it manually but I want to capture the PID in the script in a variable so I can say: `kill $variable` (that has the PID value in it).

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend your manual method to make it work automatically:

```
pid=$(ps -ef | grep run | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Ugh.  `pid=$(ps -ef | awk '/[r]un/ { print $2 }'`

Comment: The problem with ps approaches is if multiple processes are running you may kill the wrong one.

Comment: since the awk process also gets found, I used an anchor to get 1 hit only on "someapplication"
`
pid=$(ps -ef | awk '/someappliation$/ { print $2 }')
`
many thanks to @tripleee for the hint here.

Answer (score 2):

A task run in the background has its PID in `$!`

```
$ sleep 30 &
[1] 21493
$ echo $!
21493
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
dbj      21493 21414  0 11:42 pts/26   00:00:00 sleep 30
```

So you should be able to capture that value and kill that PID later.

Comment: The OP does not start a background process via the shell. Instead the command backgrounds itself. The shell cannot output the background process id via `$!` in this case because it does not have that information.

Comment: Most processes that background themselves have an option to not do that,  which makes later killing them much simpler.